# VLOOKUP a HYPERLINK formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

Not sure if this has been asked yet, but I am trying to do a VLOOKUP in an IF to return a Hyperlink.

Sheet 1, Cell A2

```
=IF($C$1>=1,VLOOKUP($A$1,'Sheet 2'!$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE),"")
```

Sheet 2

```
B1: =HYPERLINK("#'Sheet3'!$A$1", "Go to Sheet 3")
B2: =HYPERLINK("#'Sheet4'!$A$1", "Go to Sheet 4")
B3: =HYPERLINK("#'Sheet5'!$A$1", "Go to Sheet 5")
```

Each value on Sheet 2 will be a Hyperlink that goes to another Sheet, not necessarily 3, hence the need to look up the value initially.  Depending on the value of Sheet 1 Cell A1, that will tell the VLOOKUP which row on Sheet 2 to go to.

So far Sheet 1 just displays the text (Go to Sheet 3) and is not clickable.  What do I need to add to do this?

Comment: I think you need to construct the hyperlink using the VLOOKUP().  Do the hyperlinks on Sheet2 need to be active and clickable, or can sheet2 just store the text (like "#'Sheet3'!$A$1") to get to the other sheets?

Comment: I would like to be able to display the text of sheet 2 on sheet 1 (like if this was about apples and sheet 2 column 2 said "In Stock" or "Out of Stock", I'd want that to display on sheet 1), but if what would be on the A1 of sheets 3-5 could be displayed on sheet 1, that would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.  If you arrange the data on your Sheet2 like this:

[image]

then you can "construct" a hyperlink that works using `VLOOKUP()`:

`=HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP($A$1,Sheet2!A1:C3,2),VLOOKUP($A$1,Sheet2!A1:C3,3))`

This formula gives a clickable link displaying the text in Column C, depending on what's in `A1`.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you, this works!  I'm working on a big project (basically DnD Beyond but in Excel and wanted the links to take them to the ability/spell descriptions) and this was a key part that was holding me up from making it exactly what I wanted.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, you just have to slightly change the way your info is set up.

In your `Sheet 2`, change B1, B2, B3, etc. just to be the text of the Sheet you want to go to.

[image]

Then on `Sheet1`, use this formula in `A2`:

```
=IF($C$1>=1,HYPERLINK("#'"&VLOOKUP($A$1,'Sheet 2'!$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE)&"'!$A$1","Link to "&VLOOKUP($A$1,'Sheet 2'!$A$1:$B$5,2,FALSE)))
```

[image]

So as `$A$1` changes on `Sheet1`, it'll look at Sheet 2 for the correct sheet to link to.